# Google Event Tracker not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-analytics, event-tracking

I've got an event tracker (located in main.js rather than an inline click handler) that is supposed to fire when a user clicks on an item with a specific class. However, my client is reporting that these event tracker never fire, or atleast he never sees a response from them. However, other GA event trackers throughout the site are working. Can anyone see any issues with my code below that could be causing this?

The js function in main.js that handles this looks like so:

```
$('.vote.complete').click(function()
{
    whence = "toCompleted";
    vote_id = $(this).data('vote_id');
    cid = $(this).data('campaign_id');

    c_title = $('#outfitPair'+cid).data('campaign_title');
    u_id = $('#outfitPair'+cid).data('other_id');

    _gaq = window._gaq;

    if(_gaq != undefined){
      _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'ViewPreviousVote', c_title, u_id]);
    }

    $('#outfitPair'+cid).find('.button.vote').removeClass('to-vote');
    $(this).addClass('to-vote');

    $.get('/campaigns/new_pair?whence='+whence+'&vote_id='+vote_id)

    return false;
});
```

The html for what is being clicked looks like:

```
<a href="#" class="button vote complete" data-vote_id="9490" data-campaign_id="5">
   <span>01</span>
</a>
```

And the script in my layout header:

```
<script>
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X']);
      _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'mywebsite.com']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();

      window._gaq = _gaq;
</script>
```

The GA Debugger returns this in my js console upon loading the web page, although nothing new shows up when I try to trigger an event tracker:

```
Registered new plugin: "linker" analytics_debug.js:5
Creating new tracker: t0 analytics_debug.js:5

Sent beacon:
v=1&_v=j11d&a=XXXXXXXXX&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=http%3A%2F%2Fapp.website.com%2Fcampaigns%2Fvote&dr=&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=Website&sd=32-bit&sr=1366x768&vp=1349x667&je=1&fl=11.8%20r800&_u=MAC~&cid=XX.XX&tid=UA-XXXXXXX-X&z=812880404

 analytics_debug.js:5
adSenseId (&a):               XXXXXXXXXX analytics_debug.js:5
apiVersion (&v):              1 analytics_debug.js:5
clientId (&cid):              XXX.XXX analytics_debug.js:5
encoding (&de):               UTF-8 analytics_debug.js:5
flashVersion (&fl):           11.8 r800 analytics_debug.js:5
hitType (&t):                 pageview analytics_debug.js:5
javaEnabled (&je):            1 analytics_debug.js:5
language (&ul):               en-us analytics_debug.js:5
location (&dl):               http://app.website.com analytics_debug.js:5
referrer (&dr):                analytics_debug.js:5
screenColors (&sd):           32-bit analytics_debug.js:5
screenResolution (&sr):       1366x768 analytics_debug.js:5
title (&dt):                  Website analytics_debug.js:5
trackingId (&tid):            UA-XXXXXXXX-X analytics_debug.js:5
viewportSize (&vp):           1349x667 analytics_debug.js:5
```

Comment: Well it's not an answer but I am having a similar issue, just found this a few minutes ago and seems to be helping me: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna/details

Comment: Do you get any errors on it?

Comment: No errors in my js console. I'll update my question with what the GA debugger returns in my console.

Comment: So no new reports appear when you click vote.complete with GA debugger saying the beacon has been sent? Not sure what that button is doing exactly but with my issue I was using a jquery ui dialog box that loaded in a different url. I was able to fix the issue using trackPageView

Answer (score 0):

Is the `other_id` value assigned to `u_id` a number?  jQuery `.data()` will try to covert to a Javascript value, and `_trackEvent` can fail silently if the `opt_label` parameter is an integer.

You can use `.attr()` to fetch an attribute value without conversion. Try:

```
u_id = $('#outfitPair'+cid).attr('data-other_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit of an old issue, but based on your debugger output, it looks like something is expecting the new "Universal Analytics" tracking code. I can tell because the debugger output shows "analytics_debug.js" instead of "ga_debug.js".

The script you give in your header is using the old async syntax. Maybe you created a property in Google Analytics and selected Universal Analytics instead of Classic. If so, you should try upgrading to the new code:

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y');
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/

And then your event code would be `ga('send', 'event', category, action, label, value);`